# Opened LDAP Connections from connection pool after server restart (UnboundId)

Tags: java, spring, ldap, mule, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I'm using [UnboundID LDAP SDK for Java](https://ldap.com/unboundid-ldap-sdk-for-java/) to query Active Directory using LDAP.

I'm creating the connection every time now so I'd like to change my code to use connections pool. I've found some examples how to create a connections pool, how to get and return the connection ([link](https://docs.ldap.com/ldap-sdk/docs/getting-started/connection-pools.html)). I plan to do so using spring components on Mule ESB server but I'm worried about opened connections after my server or AD server restarts or communication problems.

How can I:

1. prevent my code from opened connections after my server restart
2. reconnect, recreate connections after AD communications problems

Comment: What exact version of Mule will you use? Are you planning to create a custom connector?

Comment: Currently 3.9 CE , planning to upgrade to 4.x within 1 year. To be honest I'm not familiar with custom connectors

Comment: I guess your question is about Java and Spring with LDAP mostly.

Comment: Yes, It seems to be the best aproach for now.